# get the timing from the client pc request to server

Tags: php, timer

i don't know if this is possible,

Is there a way to get the time taken when a user at the client pc make a request to the server.

time start - submit request
time end - request reach server

time needed = time end - time start = xxx secs?

regards

Comment: Get the time client side, then subtract it from the server time. Make sure to account for timezones or just use epoch.

Comment: which server? your server where you place your site? or a different one apart from your hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Use the code accordingly on request making and request processing sections.

Answer (score 0):

For client side, you would need Javascript, something like the following should do the trick.

```
 var currentTime = new Date()
  var hours = currentTime.getHours()
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

  if (minutes < 10)
  minutes = "0" + minutes

  document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b>")
```

Here is a list of additional JS Date and Time functions:

http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_date_and_time_functions.cfm

let me know if i can help you further